# Hibernate и многопоточность

Tags: java, hibernate, concurrency, transaction

Здравствуйте. Прошу разъяснить особенности работы hibernate при использовании нескольких потоков.

Пример: есть функция покупки товара в интернет-магазине; если товар на складе есть в достаточном количестве, то осуществляется покупка.
Код функции примерно такой:

```
Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
try {        
    session.getTransaction().begin();

    // запрос количества товара из БД; 
    // если товара меньше, чем нужно клиенту, то откат транзакции, 
    // в противном случае - успешное оформление покупки    

    session.getTransaction().commit();
}
catch ( Exception e ) {        
    if ( session.getTransaction().getStatus() == TransactionStatus.ACTIVE
            || session.getTransaction().getStatus() == TransactionStatus.MARKED_ROLLBACK ) {
        session.getTransaction().rollback();
    }        
}
finally {
    session.close();        
}
```

Проблема возникает при тестировании функции.
1. Если тест однопоточный, то всё отрабатывает нормально и товар при покупке списывается со склада в количестве, соразмерном количеству покупок.
2. Если вызов функции покупки товара запустить в нескольких потоках (имитация работы web-клиента), то товар будет покупаться столько раз, сколько потоков запущено, но спишется со склада только один раз.
3. Если в тесте добавить паузу между запусками потоков, например 1 сек

```
for (Thread thread : threads){
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    thread.start();
}
```

то тест отрабатывает нормально, то есть количество списываний товара со склада соразмерно числу покупок.

**Вопрос:** как устранить ошибку множественных покупок в многопоточном тесте?

Comment: Что значит "осуществляется покупка"?

Comment: @Sergey "Осуществляется покупка", это значит заводится сущность "покупка" с заданным количеством единиц товара и добавляется в базу данных; в пределах этой же транзакции у сущности "товар" списывается количество на складе этого товара, равное купленному количеству единиц.

Comment: Если сущности покупки создаются всегда, а списание происходит не всегда, значит они выполняются в разных транзакциях или уровень изоляции транзакции недостаточный. Думаю, стоит показать код сущностей и конкретный код покупки/списания.